# Does git break on triangle merges like "A->B; A->C; C->B"?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have 3 branches: `master`, `feature1` and `feature2`. Both feature branches are branched out of `master`. I finished `feature2` and made a `feature2->master` pull request. However, I can't wait for the PR to be approved, and then get `feature2` into `feature1` by doing a `master->feature1` merge. I need `feature2` in `feature1` *now*. Will the following approach cause any problems:

1. merge `feature2` into `feature1`
2. wait for someone to approve the PR and merge `feature2` into `master`
3. some time down the road, bring the long-lived branch `feature1` up to date with any changes from `master` by merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git can definitely handle the scenario you mentioned. However, you have to think whether it is really what you want and whether this agrees with the branching model you are using.

The only problems that can arise are related to your workflow. For example, what happens if the pull request is not approved, or during review you have to change something fundamental regarding `feature2`?

But assuming these kind of problems are handled by the workflow you are using, strictly from a git perspective, what you plan to do is perfectly fine.